# SQL select from 2 tables with multiple inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL 2008:
I am trying to get data (ie merge) from two tables (TODO (T) and TODO_OPERATOR(Z)) which have the same fields but different data, and then use 2 inner joins on the merged data. Not sure how to do it. An provided @id parameter would be 001 for example. Do you merge the T and Z tables in a select first somehow, and then do the INNER JOINS?

```
SELECT
T.*, Z.*, TT.lookup_desc todo_type_desc, TS.lookup_desc status_desc
FROM TODO T
CROSS JOIN TODO_OPERATOR Z
INNER JOIN LOOKUP TT ON T.todo_type=TT.lookup_id, Z.todo_type=TT.lookup_id
INNER JOIN LOOKUP TS ON t.status=TS.lookup_id, z.status=TS.lookup_id
WHERE id=@id
```

Simplified table fields would be:

TODO and TODO_OPERATOR:

id, status, todo_type

LOOKUP:

lookup_id, lookup_desc

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: Which table does column id in the where clause belong to? Anyway, give us all table definitions!

Comment: Not many people would know with that volume of information. Can you describe your tables, the data and what you're trying to achieve? Also what DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT

A.*

,TT.lookup_desc todo_type_desc

,TS.lookup_desc status_desc

FROM

(select id, status, todo_type from TODO
UNION ALL select id, status, todo_type from TODO_OPERATOR) A

INNER JOIN LOOKUP TT ON A.todo_type=TT.lookup_id

INNER JOIN LOOKUP TS ON A.status=TS.lookup_id

WHERE id=@id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
T.*, Z.*, TT.lookup_desc todo_type_desc, TS.lookup_desc status_desc  
FROM TODO T  
INNER JOIN TODO_OPERATOR Z  
ON Z.todo_type = T.todo_type  
AND z.status = T.status
INNER JOIN LOOKUP TT ON T.todo_type=TT.lookup_id  
INNER JOIN LOOKUP TS ON T.status=TS.lookup_id  
WHERE id=@id
```

I am not sure if this helps you, the information you give is a bit minimal.

Comment: thanks but that's not quite what I am after, have updated my question hope that helps a bit more.